# C# MVC Entity Framework with testability

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm thinking a bit about "best practice" regarding testability and the best way to define a particular action.

In the SportsStore application (from Pro ASP.NET MVC 4), for the AdminController, we have the following two methods in the AdminController.cs file:

**IProductRepository**

```
namespace SportsStore.Domain.Abstract {
    public interface IProductRepository {

        IQueryable<Product> Products { get; }

        void SaveProduct(Product product);  //Defined in EFProductRepository

        void DeleteProduct(Product product);  //Defined in EFProductRepository
    }
}
```

**AdminController:**

```
private IProductRepository repository;

public ViewResult Edit(int productId) {
    Product product = repository.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productId);
       ...
    }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(int productId) {
        Product prod = repository.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productId);
        ...
    }
```

As I noticed, we are basically doing the same bit of logic, that being, finding the productID.  If productId changes at all, to something else, we need to change this in two spots.  This can be tested, easily, though, since the controller itself is making the Linq call.

I was thinking that I could put this into the equivalent of the EFProducts (so the database implementation of the IProducts interface), but this creates a tie to a database state of some kind.  I'd like to avoid this in my unit tests as it increases testing complexity a fair amount.

Is there a better place to put this FindOrDefault logic, rather than in the controller, yet keep a good amount of testability?

Edit1: Adding the definition for the repository, which points to an interface

Comment: Since it seems like you are using a repository, you should have a method in your repository named `FindById(int Id)` and then you use that method from the controller, instead of doing a `FirstOrDefault` every time.

Comment: I don't think a repository is something that is very interesting test wise.  It either works or not and, at most, you can cover that in 1 unit test.  My suggestion would be to move that code into a business layer and do your testing there.  If you are using IRepository, and DI, you can just mock the repository.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  @SOfanatic - The only issue with adding this to the repository is then my ties to the database when testing.  Added more code above to hopefully make it more clear what the book is doing.  Having the unit tests tied to the state of the database adds a lot of complication.

Comment: @Maess - Thanks also for the feedback.  Yeah, that's kinda how the book does it.  The logic is duplicated in the business layer..and that in of itself was what worried me.  From a "best practices standpoint", I wasn't sure if that was right or not.  In Rails, I notice most business logic is in the model, and the not controllers.  Maybe the convention more in C# is to have a bit more of the logic in the controller?

Comment: The logic should, IMO, reside in a business layer that is consumed by the controller, think service layer.  The controller should just care about routing the correct data to the view and handling data that comes into a given action.

Comment: If you don't want to add this to the repository then you should do what @Maess said and add a business layer.

Comment: *nods* Yeah, makes sense.  Thanks to both of you for the feedback.  I'll keep it in the controller since it seems that's what SportsStore does.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The responses under my question discuss the possibilities.  Both the book and @maess agree in keeping the logic for this particular part in the controller.  The comments under my question are worth looking at, as both @SOfanatic and @Maess provided fantastic input.

Comment: When I read through the comments, I interpret different advice. Maess suggests taking the logic out of the controller and into a service layer, while SOfanatic suggests taking the logic out of the controller and putting it into the repository. In neither case should you leave the logic in the controller. Just like in Rails, the logic should be in the Model (service layer/repository), and not in the Controller.